# undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can we fix this error? Its caused because date_started is null right now since the User hasn't created the habit:

```
NoMethodError in Habits#new
Showing /Users/galli01anthony/Desktop/pecoce/app/views/habits/_form.html.erb where line #29 raised:
undefined method `to_date' for nil:NilClass
n_days = ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday }
```

The logic is so that `levels` can figure out how many days has passed since `date_started`.

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments, as: :commentable
has_many :levels
serialize :committed, Array
validates :date_started, presence: true
before_save :set_level
acts_as_taggable
scope :private_submit, -> { where(private_submit: true) }
scope :public_submit, -> { where(private_submit: false) }

def save_with_levels
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.levels.build
    self.save
end

def self.comitted_for_today
  today_name = Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
  ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
  where(id: ids)
end 

def levels
        committed_wdays = committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize) }
        n_days = ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday }
        actual_days = n_days - self.missed_days

  case n_days     
      when 0..9
        1
      when 10..24
        2
      when 25..44
        3
      when 45..69
        4
      when 70..99
        5
      else
        "Mastery"
    end
end

attr_accessor :missed_one, :missed_two, :missed_three

private
  def set_level
    self.level = levels
  end   
end
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What statement did you execute that resulted in the error? On which line did the error occur? That's a bad link, but you should avoid links to code because links, like promises, are made to be be broken, and we don't like having broken questions on SO, do we?

Comment: Sorry about that @CarySwoveland updated question. Thanks.

Comment: I am guessing you need self.date_started instead.

Comment: That gives `bad value for range` error @RailsOuter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a guard to your `levels` method:

```
def levels
  return 0 unless date_started

  # all the other code...
end
```